# Error while passing Data from a textView to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I tried to use

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func saveTextToVar(sender: UIButton) {
    var exercises: NSString = textField.text
}
```

...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController;

        svc.exercises = textField.text

    }
```

to save the variable "exercises" typed in the *textField* to *ViewController*, Where I declared the variable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate {

var exercises = ["a","b","c"]
```

(It should be used as components in a *UIpickerView*) But on the ViewController2 there is an error occurring saying.
**'String' is not convertible to '[String]'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says your exercises var is typed as string array and you are passing string value to it. In order to make this work you have to append string from your text field to exercises array in prepareForSegue method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender:     AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
    var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController;

    svc.exercises.append(textField.text)

}
```

EDITED: Since you need to add multiple exercises from your root view controller you should save them all in variable inside your root view controller then add all new values to ViewController exercises. So your code should look like the fowllowing

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var exercises: [String] = []

@IBAction func saveTextToVar(sender: UIButton) {
    exercises.append(textField.text)
} 

override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender:     AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
    var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController;

    svc.exercises = svc.exercises + self.exercises

}}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working right now. But can you tell me how to add more than one new variable? I mean whenever I added something and add a new one the information of the old one seems gone.

Comment: EDIT: The variable is also gone if I just switch between the Viewcontrollers while testing. Seems like the new variable isn't saved right.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can add multiple exercises. 
But I need the "exercises" to be stored - like in a to-do list app.

Comment: @santaklaus805 storing data is completely different thing from what you asked first. A good starting point might be [apple data management for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! You can save the titles for the PickerView somewhere (CoreData to persist them permanently or a normal Array if you don't need them permanently stored) and then dynamically load them in UIPickerViewDelegate's

```
pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:) here.

In my own app I have a `dataModel` in which I store all the relevant data for a given module in my app. I load the titles of my PickerView dynamically like this:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return dataModel.levels[row]
}
```

And I also implement

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dataModel.levels.count
}
```

to make sure it always has the right number of rows in the component.

Comment: The original question (to which this answer applies) was: Is it possible to let the user of my App be able to add variables to a PickerView using a textfield and a save button in a different Viewcontroller?

I've already got an Pickerview with 3 existing variables - like "1","2","3" and a second Viewcontroller with file - but how to add "4","5", ... while using the App and saving this variables.